# running time dependent workflow when datetime changes

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

Is it possible to fire a time dependent workflow rule where the criteria is anytime a datetime field changes, fire the time dependent action 2 hours before the datetime field?  I can't seem to get this to work.

Comment: First, I assume you mean firing 2 hours before the new field value. Next, is the date-time field a formula field? I strongly suspect the answer is no, because the workflow formula would first need to check and see if the new value was at least 2 hrs in advance of now().

Comment: If you set the Time trigger to be 2 hours before the DATETIME FIELD it will automatically adjust when the diatomite field changes. If the field is a formula field, then use a workflow to set a hidden diatomite field. You can check the pending time based workflows under setup -> Monitoring -> Time Base Workflows to see it happening. If the trigger diatomite ends up being in the past I do not think it will fire

Comment: No, it isn't a formula field.  I set the workflow rule criteria to: `DATETIME Field not equal to null` and it works.  Seems a little strange why this works, but from my initial testing it appears to work.